# Django Performance, APIView vs ViewSet

Tags: python, django

I was looking at building a star topology type model with a CI/CD workflow, with a white list based signal flow, and with that design model I want to integrate APIs, but I want to optimize for performance to push my code to the limits.

I was looking at APIView vs ViewSet, where one allows me to do a wide array of things, to include interacting with other APIs with an API, whereas the other is pretty well defined with preset tasks in mind, typically focused towards working with specific systems and models, but I wanted to also know if by doing so it gained a performance boost, or potentially gained a performance hit by being focused.

I'm not entirely sure how to test it either. What are some recommendations on how to effectively test API performance on a side by side basis?

My thoughts are to create a python script that queries the system with a specific predefined load, run a series of tasks with that predefined load, and tags the start and stop time. Fastest time wins obviously, but is that a fair assessment?

Are there any previously built tools for this, and if so, what are they?

I really appreciate the help, and will make available all of my findings so that we can all have a clear definition of what the specific difference in performance of the two are, on a percentage basis, with charts hopefully :), cause data, and I'm sure someone needs it for a thesis...somewhere.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to compare. Are you talking about the django-rest-framework?

Comment: There seem to be a number of misconceptions in this question. Neither ViewSet nor APIView have anything to do with "interacting with other APIs". APIView is just the base class that all DRF views, including viewsets, are based on. So it doesn't make sense either to talk about performance differences; an APIView doesn't do anything by itself, so there is no performance to measure.

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes, the DRF. Based on the content Im looking at, they are the two primary classes used to create a custom API, which is why I asked. One works by defining a series of functions, while the other supports a series of effectively pre-defined functions, at least to the best of my knowledge. Once you add the functions, they are the same result, an API, but not done by the same class. As such, one should be the better performer, even at the exact same function. At least theoretically. Otherwise, there would be no point to having made both in the first place by the Core Django team.

Comment: DRF isn’t made by the Django Core team. It’s a 3rd party package. Anyway, what you say makes very little sense. A ViewSet inherits from APIView so they are basically the same (a ViewSet **is an** APIView). They allow different programming patterns that’s all. When you inherit from APIView to add your own business logic you also add some code. The performance difference is nonexistent or irrelevant if you are talking about a few more or less lines of code.

Comment: @dirkgroten  this is very good to know, I didnt know this. The instructor made it appear on some of the content Im currently watching that they were separate. If thats the case though, why does he have me to import viewset under rest_framework, and APIView from rest_framework.views?

I also found this for contributors: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/internals/committers/

Tom Christie, who made django rest framework, surprisingly isnt on the list, even though he supports DRF full time.

Comment: As I said, DRF project team is not related to Django project team. Some contributors might overlap, but they are supported by entirely different organisations that have no link to each other. As to your import question, I'm not sure I understand. [`ViewSet`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/viewsets.py#L192) is defined in **viewsets.py** and [`APIView`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L104) in **views.py**. There's nothing to it.